# MATLAB CPU usage out of control, even with -singleCompThread

Tags: multithreading, matlab, cpu, cpu-usage

I've got a user who is asking why his MATLAB processes are reading as utilizing 800% CPU usage in `top`.  He has four such MATLAB processes.  Here's some specs regarding the server he's on:

```
# physical processors: 4
abc@server1[~]$ grep "physical id" /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | wc -l
4

# cores per processor: 8
abc@server1[~]$ grep "cpu cores" /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | cut -d ":" -f2
 8

# logical cores: 32
abc@server1[~]$ grep -c "processor" /proc/cpuinfo
32
```

4 processes using 800% = 3200.  8 cores x 4 CPUs = 3200.  Coincidence?  Somehow I doubt it, but I've really got nothing else to contribute to the idea pile, considering these are running with -singleCompThread enabled.  Could his code be inefficient or something and causing poor performance or something like that that is out of our control?

What can I look for/do to help diagnose why his CPU usage is through the roof?

Just for completion sake, here's what `top` looks like (abbreviated to just show his tasks):

```
Tasks: 768 total,   3 running, 763 sleeping,   2 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.1%sy, 99.9%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  132141096k total, 52020588k used, 80120508k free,  3343272k buffers
Swap: 16383992k total,        0k used, 16383992k free, 38806216k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
16179 user      30  10 3732m 220m  78m S 804.3  0.2   1006:24 MATLAB
16346 user      30  10 3729m 221m  78m S 799.2  0.2 977:04.20 MATLAB
16491 user      30  10 4167m 225m  78m S 788.9  0.2 958:12.45 MATLAB
16623 user      30  10 3473m 227m  78m S 785.1  0.2 960:48.42 MATLAB
```

Edit: just to clarify, although it says "MATLAB" is his command in `top`, `htop` reveals the full command as including -singleCompThread.

Comment: Is the user perhaps running multi-threaded MEX functions? The `-singleCompThread` switch does not control external functions, just built-in MATLAB functions.

Comment: Definitely a possibility!  This gives me something I can ask him that I didn't even know about.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, when in `top`, hit `f` to have it switch to displaying the full command line to verify the switch is in fact in use. And depending on your OS, you can hit `k` to have it switch the usage scaling to 100% is really 100% of system max.

Comment: @chappjc Bingo!  The user confirmed that he had multi-threaded MEX functions!  But now he's asking if there's any way to control those to only use one thread :/

Comment: I made an answer out of my correct guess.  I made a comment there about MEX functions too.  Could you accept and/or upvote? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the user is not running multi-threaded MEX functions. The `-singleCompThread` switch does not control external functions, just built-in MATLAB functions.

There would need to be code changes to the MEX functions to accept an input argument indicating the maximum number of threads. This should be no big deal. I do this in my threaded MEX functions. I'd be surprised if the author did not create some mechanism for specifying the number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Is your user using functionality (such as `matlabpool` or `parfor`) from Parallel Computing Toolbox? These will start up multiple MATLAB Worker processes - typically, and by default, one per processor or per core - each of which is run with `-singleCompThread` enabled.

This is done to explicitly parallelize a computationally intensive operation across those MATLAB Workers. Those will quite possibly max out the cores they're running on (that's the point of them).

Comment: I thought about that, but if as you say the workers are started with `-singleCompThread` by default (good to know!), then each MATLAB process would max out at 100% (maybe a little bit more for non-computational threads) rather than 800%. This is with `top` running in Irix mode as with the OP. The `top` output shown indicated 4 MATLAB processes each using 8 cores.